# Get the callstack(s) when a kernel32.dll function is called

Tags: windows, debugging

I have a process that changes its current directory, and I would like to know when and where it happens. How could I do that?

I tried setting a breakpoint in `SetCurrentDirectoryA`/`SetCurrentDirectoryW` with Visual Studio, but it does not work.

Comment: Keep in mind that CWD can be set in other ways as well - like through FindFirstFile; I'm not sure whether FFF internally calls SCD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you debugging one of your own programs, or one that you don't have the source code for? The Visual Studio debugger isn't very friendly with regards to debugging no-source applications; in that case, I would recommend [WinDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) or [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) - or even skipping the debugger and write an instrumented logger using [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/).

### EDIT:

Try setting a breakpoint at `{,,kernel32.dll}_SetCurrentDirectoryA@4` - peculiar syntax and requires decorated names. Haven't tried it myself, but found it [here](http://entrian.com/blog/setting-a-visual-studio-breakpoint-on-a-win32-api-function-in-user32dll/). Google keywords: "*visual studio breakpoint api*" :)

Comment: I am debugging a plugin of mine running in a program that I don't have the source code. EasyHook seems interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach/debug the process using native code. If you by mistake are debugging using managed code you will not hit those breakpoints.

Comment: You should be able to set breakpoints at API entry points. Are you using a symbol server to get the symbols? If I remember correctly I placed my breakpoint at the first assembler instruction of the API function when I last tried to do something similar to what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, I use a symbol server, abd kernel32.dll symbols are correctly loaded, but I cannot set a breakpoint in SetCurrentDirectoryA, at least in Visual Studio 2005 (it says the function cannot be found).

Answer (score 0):

Your program may be changing directories using the msvcrt functions.
You should try placing breakpoints on these functions as well:

```
_chdir
_chdrive
```

Comment: Those will eventually wind up in the kernel32 SetCurrentDirectoryA/W functions - safer to break on those and step back to user code.