# Assigning a Functional breakpoint to windows dll/API function call

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I am trying to set a breakpoint for whenever a kernel32.dll function is called. Similar to this [Get the callstack(s) when a kernel32.dll function is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805068/get-the-callstacks-when-a-kernel32-dll-function-is-called)

I assign a function breakpoint, but after assigning it has the symbol saying they will never be hit and they don't. I need to do it in x86 but can't even get this simple 64 bit one to work.

I did check "Microsoft Symbol Servers" in Tools->Options/Debugging/Symbols but the cache directory is still empty. I think this is the problem but not sure. How do I make sure the dll debug symbols are loaded correctly?

Example code.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace DebugAPI
{
  class Program
  {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern System.UInt32 GetCurrentProcessorNumber();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var num = GetCurrentProcessorNumber();
      Console.WriteLine("Proc# " + num.ToString());
    }
  }  
}
```

I tried two ways of doing the Function Breakpoints for 64bit.
Kernel32!GetCurrentProcessorNumber
{,,kernel32.dll}GetCurrentProcessorNumber

For x86 I tried the following
{,,kernel32.dll}_GetCurrentProcessorNumber@4 //Not sure if @4 is correct

Comment: "not sure if @4 is correct" that number cannot be guessed, it is related to the calling convention and number of arguments. [good explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40031574/1132334) `GetCurrentProcessorNumber` is void, so it would be optional or zero

Comment: That is why I tried the 64bit version that doesn't need the flags, but it is not void, it returns an unsigned int 32.

Comment: Sorry I read that wrong. When you said void I thought return type. So yes, it is 0. My issues was a combination, not selecting "Enable Native code debugging" and VS2017 x64 bug.

Answer (score 1):

For the record here are the full steps for setting up the breakpoints using GetCorrent ProcessorNumber as an example. Note VS2017 seems to have a bug with x64 platform target. Must be x86 or anycpu.

1. In Solution Explorere right click "YourProject"->Properties->Debug->"Enable native code debugging" = checked
2. In the Main Menu Debug->Options->Debugging->Symbols->"Microsoft Symbol Servers" = checked. & assign a cache path
3. Add Functional Breakpoint Debug->New Breakpoint->Functional Breakpoint.

[Name Options]

[x86 & x64] - Function Name = Kernel32!GetCurrentProcessorNumber Language = All

[x86] Function Name = {,,kernel32.dll)GetCurrentProcessorNumber Language = All

[x86] Function Name = _NtGetCurrentProcessorNumber@0 Language = All (Reference for # after @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/40031574/1132334 credit - dlatikay)

Note : First time debug it takes a while to download the symbols.