How to add a breakpoint to a function inside a windows DLL (user32.dll) in Visual Studio 22
I'm trying to intercept a call to GetClassInfoW.
I have already loaded the user32.pdb in Visual Studio, but I can't seem to find where I can view the symbols in the DLL and add a breakpoint. x64dbg has this feature where you can the list of symbols in the DLL, so I don't see a reason Visual Studio can't do it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53886531/17034
